# Sound after click the button and modal window opening

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I would like to make a sound after clicking on a button and opening a modal window, I would be grateful for help, no form data is sent to the server, this is just a visual improvement, like clicking on the submit button and the sound of sending a message or email

```
<button class="rent-yacht-send-button" type="submit" data-modal-open>
          Send<svg class="send-arrows-icon" width="18" height="8">
            <use href="../img/icons.svg#icon-arrow-right"></use>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal window  -->
    <div class="backdrop is-hidden" data-modal>
      <div class="modal-window">
        <button class="modal-btn" type="button" data-modal-close>
          <svg class="icon-modal" width="24" height="24">
            <use href="../img/icons.svg#icon-close-modal"></use>
          </svg>
        </button>
        <picture>
          <source media="(min-width:768px)" srcset="./img/rent/img-modal@1x.png 1x, ./img/rent/img-modal@2x.png 2x" />
          <source
            media="(min-width:320px)"
            srcset="./img/rent/img-modal-mobile@1x.png 1x, ./img/rent/img-modal-mobile@2x.png 2x"
          />
          <img src="./img/rent/img-modal@1x.png" alt="Thanks for confirming your order" class="modal-image" />
        </picture>
        <h3 class="modal-heading">Thank You</h3>
        <p class="modal-p"
          >Thank you for choosing Yacht Adventures, your booking details have been received and our team will be in
          touch shortly to confirm your reservation and provide any additional information or assistance you may
          need.</p
        >
      </div>
    </div>
```

I found several scripts but they work crookedly, or do not perform their function at all

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code  : [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ux9a286y/)

```
<button id="buzzButton">Click me to hear buzz</button>


// Function to create a buzz sound
  function buzzSound() {
    const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    const oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
    oscillator.type = 'sine'; // You can also try 'square', 'sawtooth', or 'triangle'
    oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(400, audioContext.currentTime);
    oscillator.connect(audioContext.destination);
    oscillator.start();
    oscillator.stop(audioContext.currentTime + 0.1); // Adjust the duration of the buzz sound here (in seconds)
  }

  // Add event listener to the button
  const buzzButton = document.getElementById('buzzButton');
  buzzButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    buzzSound();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP is missing the required JavaScript, plus the HTML is incomplete -- there's no `<form>` tag, only the end tag `</form>`. Normally I'd leave a comment, but I'm bored. Details are commented in example below.

```js
// Reference <form> by #id or [name]
const form = document.forms.main;

// Create an Audio Object
const fart = new Audio("https://soundbible.com/mp3/Wont Start Fart-SoundBible.com-1643093672.mp3");

/** 
 * Register the "submit" event to the <form>
 * When the <button>Open</button> is clicked, the 
 * "submit" event is triggered and the event handler
 * open(event) is called.
 */
form.onsubmit = open;

/**
 * This event handler passes the Event Object by 
 * default.
 * line 1. Stops the default behavior of <form> when
 *         "submit" event is triggered.
 * line 2. Plays MP3 file.
 * line 3. Opens the <dialog> (for demo purposes).
 */
function open(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fart.play();
  document.querySelector("dialog").showModal();
}
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form id="main">
  <button>Open</button>
</form>

<dialog>
  <form method="dialog">
    <h1></h1>
    <button>OK</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an audio tag and set the audio url to it's src value. Then

```
let btn = document.getElementById(Id);
let audio = document.getElementById(audioid);
btn.onclick = () => {
  audio.play();
}
```

Comment: this will not work on safari

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).